# Strange values being output to screen from ruby script

Tags: ruby

```
define_method :hash_count do 
  hash = ''
  hash << 'X' while hash.length < 25
  hash # returns the hash from the method
end

puts hash
```

I was expecting

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

To be outputted to the screen. Instead I get bizarre random numbers such as

```
3280471151433993928
```

and

```
-1945829393073068570
```

Could someone please explain? Scoping in Ruby seems way weirder than in PHP/Javascript!

Comment: you're not calling your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you expect this. It is a scope problem.

The variable `hash` already exists both inside and outside of the block as a function call. Whenever you declare a variable or function with the same name you will be shadowing it in that scope - that is, make the older invalid and using your just defined behaviour for that name.

In your case, you declared it in the scope of your block, and so shadowed the `Object#hash` function as a string variable inside the `do/end` block. However, the variable was not shadowed outside of your block, and thus kept the original function call.

So, for example

```
hash = ''
define_method :hash_count do 
  hash << 'X' while hash.length < 25
  hash # returns the hash from the method
end

puts hash
```

Should work as you expected because you are shadowing the hash in the same scope your are using puts. For similar reasons, if you do

```
def hash_count
  a = ''
  a << 'X' while hash.length < 25
  a # returns the hash from the method
end

puts a
```

it should raise an undefined variable error, because it is not defined in this scope.

Answer (score 1):

Hello again :) Try this:

```
def hash_count
  hash = ''
  hash << 'X' while hash.length < 25
  hash # returns the hash from the method
end

puts hash_count
```

You have called `hash`, which is the same as `self.hash`. See [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) for details about the `hash` method. Note: `hash` outside of the method is not the same as `hash` (the string) within your method, because `hash` (the string) is defined in the method scope.

**Note:** You may still use `define_method :hash_count do`, but from the code I've seen here, a simple `def hash_count` is more readable.